# How to set field base on 'in' clause?

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to do

`update my_table set bool_column = id in (1,5,8);`

So that 3 rows will get true and others false. But oracle says: `SQL command not properly ended`
how can I achieve this?

Comment: What is the data type of the colunm? Oracle doesn't have boolean.

Comment: Where is the `where` ? :)

Comment: @Patrick number(1,0); @david why do i need `where`? i want to update all rows

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Update statement need few parameters:

1. table that you will be modifying (my_table in this case)
2. columns that you are modifying (bool_column in this case)
3. expression that will be evaluated to match column type (here is where we have a problem)
4. filtering condition to limit number of updated rows (empty in this case)

I listed all of them as it is not quite clear what type is bool_column and whether you want to update all rows or just 3.

There is no boolean column in oracle, so expression `id in (1,5,8)` could not be converted to any known data type. Oracle is not expecting boolean expression to the right of bool_column.

your bool_column datatype is either number or varchar/char. So, instead of True/False, you have 1/0, 'Y'/'N' or something similar.
I would assume that you have 'Y'/'N'.

Then your statement may look like this:

```
update my_table set
bool_column = case when id in (1,5,8) then 'Y' else 'N' end
```

Another option is to set only rows with 1,5,8 and leave the rest of them empty (assuming False):

```
update my_table set
bool_column = 'Y'
where id in (1,5,8)
```

But for this aproach, you need to be sure to start with empty/false bool_column.

Answer (score 2):

You could use a `case` statement:

```
update my_table
set    bool_column =
       case
       when id in (1,5,8)
       then 1
       else 0
       end
where ...
```

Note that Oracle doesn't have a boolean data type, so maybe you are using `number` or `char`.